# Replacing __LINE__ macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I read about macros using [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

> **__LINE__** : expands to the source file line number, an integer constant, can be changed by the `#line` directive

I made c++ program to test `__LINE__` macro.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#line 10
#define L __LINE__

int main() 
{
    #line 20
    int i = L;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
20
```

Why output of the above code is `20`? Why does not 10?

Comment: [C DR 483](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_483)

Comment: TL;DR: A macro doesn't expand when it's defined.  It expands each time when (and where) it is used.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b - That's a bad TL;DR. I think the OP's confusion is that, at least on the face of it, `#define L __LINE__` *uses* `__LINE__`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to print `10` then change `L` into something that is not a macro:

```
constexpr int L = __LINE__;
```

Otherwise the *macro* `L` would be substituted on the line `int i = L;` and become:

```
int i = __LINE__;
```

Where it will have to be substituted again for the line number, and read the last `#line` directive.

Recall that macros perform token substitution. When you `#define L __LINE__` it only specifies what **tokens** should `L` be substituted for when it appears in the source. It does not substitute anything at the point of `L`'s own definition.

[C++ - [cpp.replace]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.replace#9) or [C - [6.10.3 Macro replacement]/9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p9)

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # define identifier replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of
>   the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing
>   tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement
>   list is then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.

Answer (score 5):

```
  #define y 42
  #define x y
```

This makes `x` defined as a sequence of preprocessing tokens that contains one token `y`. Not the token `42`.

```
  cout << x;
```

This will expad `x` to `y` and *then* `y` to `42`.

```
#undef y
#define y "oops"
```

`x` is still defined as `y`.

```
cout << x;
```

You guess what happens. `__LINE__` isn't special in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Your [#line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/line) preprocessor directive changes the value to `20`:

```
#line 20
```

The macro is expanded where used (not where defined) which is in your `main()` function,  after the preprocessor directive which changes the value to `20`.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding was thinking that `__LINE__` would be expanded at the `#define L __LINE__`, rather than where `L` is used.